# Use RTL Direction when Localization is LTR In React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I have used `i18n` to use multiple languages in my React Native application.

The problem is when `Localization` setting is based on `LTR` I can't change the `TextInput` direction to `RTL`. 
I have tried `writingDirection` but it only work's in IOS.
I have tried `textAlign` as well but got nothing :(.

Here is my `i18n` Setting and `TextInput` sample code :

`i18n.js`

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import fa from '../locales/fa';
import en from '../locales/en';

I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
Localization.locale = 'en';

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { fa, en };
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;

export default i18n;
```

`TextInput` sample code

```
<TextInput
 style={{textAlign: 'right'}}   // here is the style that does'nt work.        
 label={i18n.t('signUp.surName')}
 value={formData.surName.value}
 onChangeText={(value) => changeHandler('surName', value)} 
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote snack example and didn't find the problem:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/text-input-align-right
May be you are using older version of expo/react-native.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The code that you sent is correct but I'm using `react-native-paper` Input text and when I tried to apply `textAlign` to it, I failed :( have you another idea?

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1076, now way. You can another controls like native-base..

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it